# Repast - Is batch run already parallelized?

Tags: repast-simphony

If I my computer has 12 cores and my model has 15 scenarios runs, is the batch run automatically distribute the initial 12 runs to each core and run the respective runs concurently to save time? If yes, I'd like to also know if I can control the use of cores, e.g. limit to using 8 cores at a time of runinng the batch runs to prevent OOM if a single run is large scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at section 2.3 Host Panel [here](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastBatchRunsGettingStarted.pdf). You'll see that the **Instances** property determines how many independent workers will be used to process the scenarios you define. E.g., if indicate Instances: 8, then 8 workers using 8 cores will be processing your 15 scenarios.